# how to dynamicalle change the acl in haproxy?

Tags: haproxy, scripting

haproxy.cfg

```
frontend http-in
    mode    http

    bind 206.189.22.155:80

    acl path-page-designer              path_beg -i $PATH
    use_backend page-designer-backend   if path-page-designer

backend page-designer-backend
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor

    server  appserver1 206.189.22.155:$PORT
```

How can I dynamically change the values of $PATH and $PORT using lu script?Can someone show me an example of an lu script for this haproxy.cfg?I will me invoking this script using a command line script with all the application specific values as parameter from my azure pipeline configuration.But for this i need to know how a sample script for this will look like.I mean need a basic idea to get me started.Plz help

Comment: you can start to use confd

Comment: hi is this a tool that has to be used along with haproxy ?

Comment: iam just looking for a way to dynamically change the values of $PATH and $PORT using lu script in haproxy!!

Comment: use     lua-load /path/to/hello.lua in the global section to load your script

Comment: can you show me an example of a lua script for changing the $PATH and $PORT dynamically?